# Can I change any member or cluster runtime reconfiguration in etcd?

Tags: runtime, cluster-computing, etcd

etcd documentation for runtime reconfiguration (v3.5) only lists:

- peer/client URL updates
- adding members
- removing members

But what if I wish to change:

- for members

  - `--quota-backend-bytes`
  - `--snapshot-count`
  - `--heartbeat-interval`
  - `--election-interval`
- for cluster

  - `--auto-compaction-retention`

Or mine `wished` updates are only applicable to the newly created cluster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way you interact (for CLI) with `etcd` during runtime is `etcdctl`. The `etcdctl` allows only:

- work with etcd alarms
- compat/defrag
- KV operations
- snapshot save/restore
- leases/grants
- member CRUD
- role CRUD
- user CRUD

Each etcd member should have same `--flag` values when joining the cluster `./etcd ...`, except `--advertise-*` addresses, `--name` and these `--*-dir`.

All above said and taking into consideration your "wishes", on fly you can:

1. Perform `snapshot/compat/defrag` using `etcdctl`

That means, if you wish to change some `--flags` except the ones I've mentioned, you have to create brand new cluster with that desired configuration. All other changes (which, of course, you can try to apply) will lead to unsafe cluster